# Docker Node:Alpine-12: how to install Chromium 73 in Dockerfile?

Tags: node.js, docker, chromium, puppeteer, alpine-linux

Since I would like to run Puppeteer@1.19 but faces error in page.pdf().

Some blobs just mentioned to downgrade Chromium from version 76 to 73. How to do it in Dockerfile with using node:alpine-12? Thanks

Below is my setting (chromium version is 76):

```
FROM node:12-alpine
########## 
## Setting for using Puppeteer (for using node:XX-alpine)
##########    
ENV CHROME_BIN="/usr/bin/chromium-browser"\
    PUPPETEER_SKIP_CHROMIUM_DOWNLOAD="true"
########## 
## Update and Install packages
##########
RUN set -x \
    && apk update \
    && apk upgrade \
    && echo "127.0.0.1 localhost" >> /etc/hosts \
    && echo "http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/testing" > /etc/apk/repositories \
    && echo "http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/community" >> /etc/apk/repositories \
    && echo "http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/main" >> /etc/apk/repositories \
    # add the packages
    ## g++: used to install NodeJS related packages
    ## chromium: used to run Puppeteer
    && apk add --no-cache g++ chromium
```

Tried to change last line to `chromium` to `chromium-browser@73` or `chromium@73` but faced below error:

> The repository tag for world dependency 'chromium@73' does not exist

FYI, error when I just installed `chromium` with running below NodeJS code:

```
Line239: await page.pdf({
            path: TEMP_DIR + filename, 
            format: 'A4',
            printBackground: true
         });
```

> printPdf() Error
>   Error: Protocol error (IO.read): Invalid parameters handle: string value expected
>        at /usr/src/app/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/Connection.js:183:56
>        at new Promise ()
>        at CDPSession.send (/usr/src/app/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/Connection.js:182:12)
>        at Function.readProtocolStream (/usr/src/app/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/helper.js:241:37)
>        at async Page.pdf (/usr/src/app/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/Page.js:988:12)
>        at async printPdf (/usr/src/app/puppeteer.js:239:9)
>        at async /usr/src/app/puppeteer.js:129:21
>      -- ASYNC --
>        at Page. (/usr/src/app/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/helper.js:111:15)
>        at printPdf (/usr/src/app/puppeteer.js:239:20)
>        at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:85:5)
>        at async /usr/src/app/puppeteer.js:129:21 {
>     message: 'Protocol error (IO.read): Invalid parameters handle: string value expected'
>   }

Comment: @Li357: cannot run your command: `/bin/sh: apt-get: not found`

Answer (score 26, accepted):

chromium73 does not exist in the edge branch which is used in nodejs base image. you have to set branch to v3.10 to download chromium73.

[alpine chromium&branch=v3.10](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/packages?name=chromium&branch=v3.10)

```
FROM node:12-alpine
RUN apk add --no-cache  chromium --repository=http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.10/main
```

verify installtion

`docker run -it --rm myalpine ash -c "apk -e info chromium"`

Comment: now the chromium version available in v3.10 is 77.0.3865.120